# Replacing source of an image with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im building an app with Phonegap. It takes xml from an rss feed and creates html from it to present a news feed. The problem is the image paths are relative. I need to replace the relative path with the full path. The images tags appear inside a "description" xml tag. I get the contents of description like this:

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function (index) {

   description = $(this).find('description').text();
   console.log('description');
```

The console output is:

```
<p>Senior Rugby</p>
<p>CBC v CBS</p>
<p>
  <span class="mjwideimg"><img width="300" height="247" src="/images/latestnews2/Resized/logo_300x247.jpg" alt="logo" />
  </span>
</p>
```

I then try to replace path with a full path. I do:

```
$(description).find('img:first').attr('src', 'http://www.domain.com/img/test.png');
```

And then get the new html with full path:

```
description = $(description).html();
console.log(description);
```

However, this is just outputting:

```
Senior Rugby
```

with everything else stripped away. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you put this as a demo in jsFiddle pls?

Answer (score 0):

When you are finding the image, is description still set to `$(this).find('description').text();`?

If so the JQuery object is not pointing to HTML element but rather a string of text that is within that element.

Try replacing description with `$(this).find('description');`

Answer (score 0):

In first `console.log` you are doing

```
description = $(this).find('description').text();
console.log('description');
```

here you are log the xml node not the variable you coded.

And in another, you did something different (this time you did it for variable)

```
description = $(description).html();
console.log(description);
```

Another point is use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

```
$(description).find('img:first').prop('src', 'http://www.domain.com/img/test.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did this:

```
description = $(this).find('description').text();

$(description).find('img').each(function(i, obj){

   src = $(obj).attr('src');

   //check if not full path 
   if(src.indexOf('http') === -1){
     //therefore its a relative path
     description = description.replace(src,"http://domain.com"+src);
   }
});
```